# Could you explain me matrices from Graph Theory?

Tags: graph-theory

My professor showed this in class:

[image]
[image]

I had to translate it to english so the translation might be slightly wrong.

Could you explain to me what this means? I thought that what the first pic said was that when you have a line that goes from point i to point k you write 1 on that coordinate on the matrix, and when you have a line that goes from k to i you write -1, but that doesn't seem to be the case with the matrix below. I don't understand when you use 0. I also don't understand why equal coordinates (i.e 1,1 or 2,2) are always 1.

Comment: Have you considered asking your professor?

Comment: @amd Its complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple kinds of these matrices. Your example is vertex-edge incidence matrix. Rows are vertices and columns are edges. If edge $k$ goes from $u_i \to u_j$ then in the $k$-th column,

- row $i$ will be $-1$,
- row $j$ will be $1$,
- and all others will be $0$.